# Random positioning images in carousel issue

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, carousel, frontend

I'm writing vanillaJS slider. When i refresh site sometimes it's work good, sometimes not. On Codepen/Snippet code works perfect.

```js
const activeEl = document.getElementsByClassName('active')[0];
const slideList = document.getElementsByClassName('slide-unit');
let activeElIndex = Array.from(activeEl.parentNode.children).indexOf(activeEl);

function sliderFunction(newActiveElIndex){
  if (newActiveElIndex != activeElIndex){
        slideList[activeElIndex].classList.remove('active');
        slideList[newActiveElIndex].classList.add('active');
        activeElIndex = newActiveElIndex;
      }
  for (let i = 0; i < slideList.length; i++){
    if (newActiveElIndex < i){
      slideList[i].style.left = (i-newActiveElIndex-1)*21.25 + 36.25 +"vw";
    } else if (newActiveElIndex > i){
      slideList[i].style.left = (i-newActiveElIndex)*21.25 +"vw";
    } else {
      slideList[i].style.left = 0 +"vw";
    }
  }
}

sliderFunction(activeElIndex);

 for (let i = 0; i < slideList.length; i++){
  slideList[i].addEventListener('click', function(){sliderFunction(i);}, false);
 }
```

```css
 .slider {
    position: relative;
    height: 45vh;
    width: 30vw;
    margin: 0 35vw 0 35vw; }
.slider .slide-unit {
      position: absolute;
      height: 50%;
      width: 50%;
      top: 25%;
      left: 0;
      background-color: pink;
      transition: all 800ms cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55); }
 .slider .slide-unit.active {
        position: absolute;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        top: 0;
        left: 0; }
```

```html
<div class="slider">

    <div class="slide-unit"></div>
    <div class="slide-unit active"></div>
    <div class="slide-unit"></div>
    <div class="slide-unit"></div>
    <div class="slide-unit"></div>
    <div class="slide-unit"></div>

  </div>
```

On firefox/chrome sometimes it's look like this:
[image]

Active (bigger) element should in center. It's some kind of bug or my mistake?

Comment: It sounds like a race condition.  Have you tried running the code after the element is loaded? What I'm thinking is that it's usually firing after all of the elements are loaded, but sometimes it's firing before they're loaded.

Comment: JS script run at the end of site. Still, even after few minutes, still stay in same bad place. On your browser everything runs good?

Comment: Yeah,  seems fine in Chrome running the snippet.